# view LVM paritions in windows 7

Tags: mount, windows-7, ext4, lvm

im trying to browse in windows an old harddisk that i got, but its a LVM patition.
How can I see a partition that is ext3/4 or part of LVM partition in windows? Anyone can recommend on a tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mount Ubuntu's partition on Windows 7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20853/mount-ubuntus-partition-on-windows-7)

Comment: I am not sure if LVM is properly supported on any tool, anyway if it is, is at some of the tools listed on the previous question.

Comment: That question (and answers) do not talk about LVM at all.

Answer (score 4):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/ can read LVM2'd EXT2/3/4 partitions.

Comment: I am not having any luck with my LVM partitions on Windows 10. None of the volumes are showing up.

Answer (score 2):

LVM is not supported on Windows.  If you want to share partitions between Linux and windows, they need to be normal partitions, not LVM, and not windows dynamic disks either.

Comment: Unsupported is a little strong, a driver doesn't exist is more accurate. There are extfs drivers for Windows and this opensource project actually has LVM support in it's TODO. http://www.ext2fsd.com/.

Comment: @ppetraki, unsupported is accurate because nobody supports LVM on Windows.  LVM support is quite outside the scope of the ext2fsd project as well.

Comment: I would suggest giving an answer that was constructive!
What is the point in saying that it is unsupported while it is still possible?
If you want to discuss personal opinions I suggest that you go join a forum :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the app to read files from LVM: http://www.chrysocome.net/virtualvolumes