# It is possible to install dual boot Ubuntu and WIndows 7, using LVM?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, lvm

I am doing a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.10, and it says than I can install Ubuntu using the entire disk and create LVM "partitions", but my plan is to install Windows 7 **using one of those LVM partitions** for dual boot. Is this possible?

What is the right strategy to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run Windows **natively** it would have understand LVM, and that seems to not be the case([1](https://superuser.com/a/235975/247027), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60240/view-lvm-paritions-in-windows-7)).

I suppose you could allocate a virtual machine disk on a LVM partition, and run Windows inside the virtual machine.

However, if you are only concerned about using LVM in Ubuntu you can

- install Windows on raw disk partitions
- Install grub on *one partitition* (to boot) and LVM on another partition and allocate all remaining volumes from inside the LVM.

Comment: So are you going to install virtual or native?

Comment: I am not going to install anything, just wanted to learn, but I use windows just for games, that being said, native.

Answer (score 0):

install windows 7 first then ubuntu over the top.  the ubuntu installer will take care of partitioning for you.  i usually split the disk in two when installing windows so i have a separate 'data' partition but you don't have to do that.  you can actually install ubuntu from within windows using the windows installer.  if in doubt do it that way because it's easy peasy to uninstall if you don't like it.

Comment: this have nothing to do with LVM, sorry

Comment: It's not perfectly relevant to LVM, Joe, but I think the poster makes one crucial observation - it's far easier to install Windows 7 FIRST, then install Ubuntu. If you do it the other way around, you'll hit horrible issues with having to re-install Grub - and I say horrible, because you'll have to take your LVM partioning into account when you do so!

Answer (score 0):

with Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer (LVM supported since version 12.10) this is not possible if you install Ubuntu on the same physical drive as Windows 7. However, I wonder myself if there is a way to do it nevertheless, maybe using other tools or do it via terminal?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add a more precise solution for the original poster to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same thing. I think it is not possible to install ubuntu first and then install windows on LVM. it is possible in the opposite way. First install windows 10 (preferably) thereafter install Hyper-v, create ubuntu machine inside VM. Add Boot entry to BCD and dual boot. Later you may install your another windows host on VM through Hyper-V and completely remove the entry of windows 10. That way your will have two virtual machines boot entry and a windows 10 host.